# Can we squeeze the table along with the text dynamically based on resolution of screen in html?

Tags: html, css-tables

I have designed a web page which is utilizing full screen in resolution 1366*768.
Now if I am viewing my webpage on some other resolution all the div tags overlap..
that thing I corrected by keeping all my webpage in a table..
but still I am getting a scroll in lower resolutions..
Can we do something like decreasing the font and image sizes based on resolution..

Comment: These overlapping divs, is there any change we can get to see those? Normally, divs don't start overlapping when you shrink the browser screen.

Answer (score 0):

Table based layouts are usually a really bad idea. The best way to make a webpage look nice for different resolutions is, to use div with a width property in percentage. A small example would be:

CSS:

```
#main{
 width: 70%;
 position: absolute;
 left: 25%;
 top:0px;
}


#left{
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 width:20%
}
img{
 width: 100%;
}
```

​

HTML:

```
<div id="left">
<p>
This is the left coulmn.<br />
This is the left coulmn.<br />
<img id="picture1" src="pic.png" />
</p>
</div>

<div id="main">
<p>
This is the main div with a lot of text.
This is the main div with a lot of text.
This is the main div with a lot of text.
This is the main div with a lot of text.
This is the main div with a lot of text.
</p>
</div>
```

[using float instead of absolute position is also a common solution, to archive different columns]
Two answer you're question about decresing the fon size based on resolution: This would be possible, using Javascript (Get the resolution, changing the image size dynamically). But it would be abusing web technoligies - so just go with CSS percentage properties. If you need help in your particular case, please post the code of your basic page structure. Also google for "CSS 2/3 column layout".

**EDIT:** shorted example code + insert a img tag

Comment: But now if i have some image in the left div then in other resolutions it is going to overlap with the other div...

Comment: what do you mean in other resolutions? Just make the image a width of 100% and it will have the width of left box. I edited my answer, please see the code